# Add constraint to a transformation matrix

Tags: transformation, constraints

I have an object, $P$, and a 3 DoF transformation matrix, $T$. In my work, I want to say that $T$ can only model pitching, heaving and surging of $P$.

Currently, I write it like this,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& & & NP = \ T \cdot P \\
& \text{subject to} & &  T = \begin{bmatrix}
    cos\ \alpha & 0 & -sin\ \alpha & d_x \\
    0    & 1 & 0    & 1 \\
    sin\ \alpha & 0 & cos\ \alpha & d_z \\
    0    & 0 & 0    & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

However, I don't think above formula is formally correct. Any idea how to improve that?

Comment: $T$ is a rotation about the $y$-axis followed by a translation by $(d_x,1,d_z)$. Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: @amd Yes.. But I don't see anyone write it like that as a constraint.